# как узнать размер окна Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Написал программу и хочу сделать исполняемый файл с помощью `pyinstaller`, но к сожалению, при запуске программы, некоторые размеры окон неверны, т.к. я задаю геометрию окна таким образом: `self.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(w, h))` В данном примере главное то, что размеры окна задаются автоматически.

При запуске программы через IDEL всё отображается правильно, но когда запускаю .exe файл, то размеры съезжают. Чтобы всё было хорошо, мне надо узнать автоматические размеры заданные окну. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод `geometry()` класса `tkinter.Tk()`, пример:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
print(root.geometry())
```

Comment: Всё работает, только добавьте скобки после `geometry`, иначе выдаёт ерунду

Answer (score 0):

Можно растянуть невидимый виджет на весь экран и измерить его размеры с помощью winfo_height и winfo_width. Приведу пример для кнопки:

```
import tkinter as tk
   
def func():
    x = button_place.winfo_width()
    y = button_place.winfo_height()
    print(x, y)
  
  
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x500')
button_place = tk.Button(root, text='', font='Times 15', command=func)
button_place.place(w=600, h=500)
  
root.mainloop()
```

Но это обычно используется для определения размеров виджетов. Для определения экрана нужна просто `root.geometry()`. Первый пример привел просто для дополнительной информации, может Вам понадобиться

Comment: `root.winfo_width()` и `root.winfo_height()` возвращают размеры окна, не нужны тут никакие невидимые виджеты.

Answer (score 0):

Гораздо проще всё, используй метод wm_maxsize() для определения размера экрана при создании объекта Tk()

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ну, уже без этого справились‍♂️ Реализовали как `.pack` и автоматическую настройку окна под размер виджетов)